# How to use Flask-Script and Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm working on on a Flask app using Flask's built in dev server.  I start it using Flask-Script.  I want to switch to using Gunicorn as the web server.  To do so, do I need to write some sort of integration code between Flask-Script and Gunicorn?  Or is Flask-Script irrelevant to running the app using Gunicorn?

Thanks in advance!

Props to @sean-lynch. The following is working, tested code based on his answer.
The changes I made were:

- Options that aren't recognized by Gunicorn are removed from `sys.argv` in `remove_non_gunicorn_command_line_args()` before trying to start the server.  Otherwise Gunicorn throws an error with a message like this: `error: unrecognized arguments: --port 5010`.  I remove `-p` because, even though it doesn't cause the error, that's only because Gunicorn thinks its the short form of its `pidfile` option, which is obviously not what's intended.
- GunicornServer.handle() signature modified to match the method it overrides i.e. Command.handle()

-

```
from flask_script import Command
from gunicorn.app.base import Application

class GunicornServer(Command):

    description = 'Run the app within Gunicorn'

    def __init__(self, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, workers=6):

        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.workers = workers

    def get_options(self):
        return (
            Option('-t', '--host',
                   dest='host',
                   default=self.host),

            Option('-p', '--port',
                   dest='port',
                   type=int,
                   default=self.port),

            Option('-w', '--workers',
                   dest='workers',
                   type=int,
                   default=self.workers),
        )

    def handle(self, app, *args, **kwargs):

        host = kwargs['host']
        port = kwargs['port']
        workers = kwargs['workers']

        def remove_non_gunicorn_command_line_args():
            import sys
            args_to_remove = ['--port','-p']
            def args_filter(name_or_value):
                keep = not args_to_remove.count(name_or_value)
                if keep:
                    previous = sys.argv[sys.argv.index(name_or_value) - 1]
                    keep = not args_to_remove.count(previous)
                return keep
            sys.argv = filter(args_filter, sys.argv)

        remove_non_gunicorn_command_line_args()

        from gunicorn import version_info
        if version_info < (0, 9, 0):
            from gunicorn.arbiter import Arbiter
            from gunicorn.config import Config
            arbiter = Arbiter(Config({'bind': "%s:%d" % (host, int(port)),'workers': workers}), app)
            arbiter.run()
        else:
            class FlaskApplication(Application):
                def init(self, parser, opts, args):
                    return {
                        'bind': '{0}:{1}'.format(host, port),
                        'workers': workers
                    }

                def load(self):
                    return app

            FlaskApplication().run()

manager.add_command('gunicorn', GunicornServer())
```

Comment: I think this can be easier, Install gunicorn in your environment, then you could make a gunicorn.conf file where you can just declare the gunicorn configuration(number of workers, bind the port, the pid, etc...), and then just call gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf runserver:app (yourrunappfile:yourapp variable)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Dhaivat said, you can just use your Flask app directly with Gunicorn.

If you still want to use Flask-Script, you will need to create a custom `Command`.  I don't have any experience with Gunicorn, but I found a similar [solution](https://bitbucket.org/youngking/flask-actions/src/381d6eea3e78/flaskext/actions/server_actions.py#cl-81) for Flask-Actions and ported it to Flask-Script, although be warned, it's untested.

```
from flask_script import Command, Option

class GunicornServer(Command):

    description = 'Run the app within Gunicorn'

    def __init__(self, host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, workers=4):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.workers = workers

    def get_options(self):
        return (
            Option('-H', '--host',
                   dest='host',
                   default=self.host),

            Option('-p', '--port',
                   dest='port',
                   type=int,
                   default=self.port),

            Option('-w', '--workers',
                   dest='workers',
                   type=int,
                   default=self.workers),
        )

    def handle(self, app, host, port, workers):

        from gunicorn import version_info

        if version_info < (0, 9, 0):
            from gunicorn.arbiter import Arbiter
            from gunicorn.config import Config
            arbiter = Arbiter(Config({'bind': "%s:%d" % (host, int(port)),'workers': workers}), app)
            arbiter.run()
        else:
            from gunicorn.app.base import Application

            class FlaskApplication(Application):
                def init(self, parser, opts, args):
                    return {
                        'bind': '{0}:{1}'.format(host, port),
                        'workers': workers 
                    }

                def load(self):
                    return app

            FlaskApplication().run()
```

You can then either register it to replace Flask's [local development server](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run) at `python manage.py runserver`

```
manager.add_command("runserver", GunicornServer())
```

or register as a new command such as `python manage.py gunicorn`

```
manager.add_command("gunicorn", GunicornServer())
```

**Edit June 2016**: With the latest version of Flask-Script, change the method `handle` with `__call__`. [old flask-script](https://github.com/smurfix/flask-script/blob/cb36eb94d6ae992458b6a66c6c2a715cddfdc4bd/flask_script/commands.py#L138) vs [new flask-script](https://github.com/smurfix/flask-script/blob/master/flask_script/commands.py#L210)

Comment: not yet. but this is more than enough to point me in the right direction.  i'll post here if i find i need to make changes to the code you provided.

Comment: Posted as promised. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Here is my Error report:   `TypeError: <gunicorn.Gunicorn object at 0x7f15bb51ef90>: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'host'`

Comment: I received the below error: 
`TypeError: <__main__.GunicornServer object at 0x106a084d0>: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy_protocol'`

Comment: Hi, i would like to ask how to link this to the way of running guincorn as [linux service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)?

Comment: Not Found given link in answer `solution `: https://bitbucket.org/youngking/flask-actions/src/381d6eea3e78/flaskext/actions/server_actions.py#cl-81

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a better version of GunicornServer based on Sean Lynch's, the command now accept all gunicorn's arguments

```
from yourapp import app
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Command, Option

class GunicornServer(Command):
    """Run the app within Gunicorn"""

    def get_options(self):
        from gunicorn.config import make_settings

        settings = make_settings()
        options = (
            Option(*klass.cli, action=klass.action)
            for setting, klass in settings.iteritems() if klass.cli
        )
        return options

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication

        app = WSGIApplication()
        app.app_uri = 'manage:app'
        return app.run()

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("gunicorn", GunicornServer())
```

Comment: @sholsapp In fact, `--reload` doesnot work as expect using gunicorn like this.  I rewrite GunicornServer at https://gist.github.com/menghan/9a632bbb0acb445f4f3a

Answer (score 6):

Based the answer of the Sean, I also wrote a version more preferred to me.

```
@manager.option('-h', '--host', dest='host', default='127.0.0.1')
@manager.option('-p', '--port', dest='port', type=int, default=6969)
@manager.option('-w', '--workers', dest='workers', type=int, default=3)
def gunicorn(host, port, workers):
    """Start the Server with Gunicorn"""
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application

    class FlaskApplication(Application):
        def init(self, parser, opts, args):
            return {
                'bind': '{0}:{1}'.format(host, port),
                'workers': workers
            }

        def load(self):
            return app

    application = FlaskApplication()
    return application.run()
```

you can run the gunicorn using command like this`python manager.py gunicorn`

Comment: I don't see any errors when I run the command, but, I could not see any server running on 127.0.0.1:6969. Did the above custom command work for you? Or is it untested?

Answer (score 2):

Flask actually has docs to run Gunicorn [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn).

You have to remember that Gunicorn is a WSGI server with some niceties.

Comment: That doesn't help if you're using flask_script.  The issue still stands that you need to pass in additional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @menghan's solution and @OutOfFoodException improvement. But remember that for `gunicorn=20.0.4` for binding server socket using `-b, --bind` [option](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-socket). And result command for me was like that:

```
python3 manage.py gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000
```

```
from yourapp import app
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Command, Option

class GunicornServer(Command):
    """Run the app within Gunicorn"""

    def get_options(self):
        from gunicorn.config import make_settings

        settings = make_settings()
        options = (
            Option(*klass.cli, action=klass.action)
            for setting, klass in settings.iteritems() if klass.cli
        )
        return options

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import WSGIApplication

        app = WSGIApplication()
        app.app_uri = 'manage:app'
        return app.run()

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("gunicorn", GunicornServer())
```

Answer (score 0):

I will elaborate further on the answer by @NinjaDQ. If you want to use `app_uri` attribute for defining for example the flask application configuration file and custom command line arguments at the same time, you need to use `WSGIApplication`. The problem is that this application `overrides` the command line arguments thus it is necessary to ignore the `sys.argv`.

```
        from gunicorn.app.base import Application

        class FlaskApplication(Application):
            def init(self, parser, opts, args):
                return {
                    "bind": "{0}:{1}".format(host, port),
                    "workers": 4
                }

            def chdir(self):
                # chdir to the configured path before loading,
                # default is the current dir
                os.chdir(self.cfg.chdir)

                # add the path to sys.path
                sys.path.insert(0, self.cfg.chdir)

            def load_wsgiapp(self):
                self.chdir()

                # load the app
                return util.import_app(self.app_uri)

            def load(self):
                return self.load_wsgiapp()

        # Important! Do not pass any cmd line arguments to gunicorn
        sys.argv = sys.argv[:2]

        wsgi_app = FlaskApplication()
        wsgi_app.app_uri = "manage:create_app('{0}')".format(config_file)

        return wsgi_app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on menghan's answer, receive all arguments from Application config.

```
from flask_script import Command, Option


class GunicornApp(Command):

    def get_options(self):
        from gunicorn.config import make_settings

        settings = make_settings()
        options = (
            Option(*klass.cli, dest=klass.name, default=klass.default)
            for setting, klass in settings.items() if klass.cli
        )
        return options

    def __call__(self, app=None, *args, **kwargs):

        from gunicorn.app.base import Application
        class FlaskApplication(Application):
            def init(self, parser, opts, args):
                return kwargs

            def load(self):
                return app

        FlaskApplication().run()
```