# Run Gunicorn from Python with FlaskScript

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask application i want to run with Gunicorn server instead of Werkzeug (even in development). But as the app is created using a `create_app` function, Gunicorn can't be started from the command line with `my_module:my_app`. Plus, i have a `manage.py` script written with the help of Flask-Script extension to run the server and some other operations.

I've tried to inherit `gunicorn.app.wsgiapp.WSGIApplication` in the same style as the solution proposed here: [How to use Flask-Script and Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566570/how-to-use-flask-script-and-gunicorn), but the `app_uri` attribute is not found on my app object.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do it ?

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the same obvious thing I once did. ;)

```
gunicorn 'my_module:create_app()'
```

Comment: this is a very helpful answer that saved me a boatload of time.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem using the recipe in the [Custom Application section of the Gunicorn documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/custom.html).  The basic idea is that you subclass `gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication` and overload `load_config` and `load`.