# Flask deployment on gunicorn with flask script

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have working flask app on my development server of flask which works fine. Now i want to take it one step further to deploy it using the gunicorn i have following code in which i can launch gunicorn but my application some where in middle drop connection but it works very fine DEV server.

I would like to know how to enable logging on with gunicorn.

I review the following que but could not get much information 
[How to use Flask-Script and Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566570/how-to-use-flask-script-and-gunicorn)

My Application has following structure and 
/home/webusr/svsapp/svsappenv

**manage.py** has following code updated my manage.py with respect to following blog post

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from gunicorn.app.base import Application

from app import  create_app,db
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell , Server
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Command,Option
from app.models import SVSFaceTab,SVSuserReg,SVSIpCamReg


app = create_app(os.getenv('SVS_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)




def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db,SVSuserReg=SVSuserReg,SVSIpCamReg=SVSIpCamReg,SVSFaceTab=SVSFaceTab)



manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


@manager.option('-h', '--host', dest='host', default='169.38.74.171')
@manager.option('-p', '--port', dest='port', type=int, default=8080)
@manager.option('-w', '--workers', dest='workers', type=int, default=10)
@manager.option('-t', '--timeout', dest='timeout', type=int ,default=90)


def gunicorn(host, port, workers,timeout):
    """Start the Server with Gunicorn"""
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application

    class FlaskApplication(Application):
        def init(self, parser, opts, args):
            return {
                'bind': '{0}:{1}'.format(host, port),
                'workers': workers,'timeout' : timeout

            }

        def load(self):
            return app

    application = FlaskApplication()
    return application.run()


@manager.command
def test():
    """Run the unit tests."""
    import unittest
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

---

```
$ python manage.py gunicorn
```

Comment: `gunicorn manage:app`? (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gunicorn)

Comment: please add that to the OP and format it, so it's easier to read.

Comment: thanks i will do that

Comment: Why do you have `from flask import Flask, request...` and `from datetime import datetime` in *manage.py*?

Comment: Does your app definitely work on the development server in its current state? `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: Yes it does work fine without any issue ...

Comment: I suggest removing those import statements I mentioned I don't see them being used anywhere, and as far as I know its atypical to have those in *manage.py*. Which means it's likely incorrect.

Comment: i removed unwanted export in manage.py still the same error ....import os
import sys
from app import  create_app,db
from flask.ext.script import Manager, Shell
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app.models import SVSFaceTab,SVSuserReg,SVSIpCamReg

Comment: One thing i found it strange when i type app:create_app it does work but its not useful since it does not server application
(svsappenv)[webusr@NiravFlask svsappenv]$ gunicorn app:create_app
[2015-12-14 12:10:25 +0000] [3570] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.1
[2015-12-14 12:10:25 +0000] [3570] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3570)
[2015-12-14 12:10:25 +0000] [3570] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-12-14 12:10:25 +0000] [3575] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3575

Comment: Copy and paste terminal output like that into the OP. Then select the output which was just pasted, and then click the code button in formatting. Also edit *manage.py* to reflect the changes you made! For the *import* statements.

Comment: the same way, works fun for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this solution based on [https://bitbucket.org/youngking/flask-actions/src/381d6eea3e78/flaskext/actions/server_actions.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#cl-81](http://flask-actions...)

```
class GunicornServer(Command):
description = 'to run the app within Gunicorn'

def __init__(self, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, workers=2):
    self.port = port
    self.host = host
    self.workers = workers

def get_options(self):
    return (
        Option('-H', '--host',
               dest='host',
               default=self.host),

        Option('-p', '--port',
               dest='port',
               type=int,
               default=self.port),

        Option('-w', '--workers',
               dest='workers',
               type=int,
               default=self.workers),
    )

def handle(self, app, host, port, workers):

    from gunicorn import version_info
    if version_info < (0, 9, 0):
        from gunicorn.arbiter import Arbiter
        from gunicorn.config import Config
        arbiter = Arbiter(
            Config(
                {'bind': "%s:%d" % (host, int(port)), 'workers': workers}
            ),
            app
        )
        arbiter.run()
    else:
        from gunicorn.app.base import Application

        class FlaskApplication(Application):
            def init(self, parser, opts, args):
                return {
                    'bind': '{0}:{1}'.format(host, port),
                    'workers': workers
                }

            def load(self):
                return app

        FlaskApplication().run()

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)
# Adding gunicorn based runserver command
manager.add_command("gunicorn", GunicornServer())
```

I am running the app like:

```
./manage.py gunicorn
```

Notice the last line manage.add_command, if you want you can just override "runserver" with GunicornServer() class.