# Post-fork connection to Cassandra under gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cassandra, gunicorn

I'm developing a Flask microservice to expose some data from a Cassandra database. It is served with `gunicorn` being called from the command line.  I'm confused regarding as to where and how to connect to the database under `gunicorn`, particularly when considering how to mock or bypass the need of the database when doing unit testing.

My first attempt was to connect at app creation time, as follows:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.debug = True

    cluster = Cluster([os.environ['CASSANDRA_HOST']])
    app.cassandra = cluster.connect(os.environ['CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE'])

    return app
```

thinking that it will make a single "global" connection reducing overhead for each individual request. This clearly fails unit testing as it'll try to connect which is not the point of a unit testing in an isolated environment of a CI pipeline.

Then, checking some [slides](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/pythonandcassandra-150319091009-conversion-gate01/95/python-and-cassandra-26-638.jpg?cb=1426774311) from Cassandra people it says that for Flask under `gunicorn` we should use `@app.before_first_request` and that as a general rule should connect "post-fork". I'm not sure what "post-fork" means in this context.

Anyhow, doing:

```
@app.before_first_request
def before_request():
    app.cluster = Cluster([os.environ['CASSANDRA_HOST']])
    app.cassandra = app.cluster.connect(os.environ['CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE'])
```

also works, but still have the same problem with the isolated unit testing.

By reading through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554355/why-is-cassandra-hanging-when-i-connect-to-it-via-gunicorn-and-flask), I guess that I'm not having issues with the connection itself as I'm creating one Cassandra session per Flask instance that is spawned by `gunicorn` *post-fork*.

Then my question would reduce to which strategy to follow to be able to unit test the endpoints without having to explicitly reach for the database.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to have one Cluster/Session per process, created on fork and held for the process lifetime. Most servers offer a post-fork 'hook' for setting up resources like this.

The Gunicorn hook is documented [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#post-fork)

uWSGI analog is reference in the [driver FAQ](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/faq.html#why-do-connections-or-io-operations-timeout-in-my-wsgi-application).