# Flask - Gunicorn returns 404 after curl to localhost on same instance

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy my Flask site with Gunicorn. This [repo](https://github.com/hansonkd/FlaskBootstrapSecurity) shows the code I am using to start with, I have added my own controllers etc.

The problem I am having is as follows:

1. `python manage.py runsever` works fine locally
2. `sudo gunicorn flask_application:app -b 127.0.0.1:8000` runs the application fine on my server.

Gunicorn logs show:

```
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3926] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.1.1
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3926] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3926] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (3926)
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3926] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3931] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3931
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3932] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3932
[2017-07-11 15:06:38 +0000] [3937] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3937
[2017-07-11 15:06:39 +0000] [3926] [DEBUG] 3 workers
[2017-07-11 15:06:42 +0000] [3932] [DEBUG] GET /profile:8000
[2017-07-11 15:06:47 +0000] [3937] [DEBUG] GET /profile
[2017-07-11 15:06:49 +0000] [3932] [DEBUG] GET /profile:8000
```

As you can see, my `curl 127.0.0.1/profile:8000` (on the same box) request comes through, no error thrown in the logs but the reposes shows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Gunicorn config:

```
workers = 3
errorlog = '/home/www/flask_project/logs/gunicorn-error.log'
accesslog = '/home/www/flask_project/logs/gunicorn-access.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566570/how-to-use-flask-script-and-gunicorn) is similar to my setup, however I am happy to just get this running directly with gunicorn rather than through Flask-Script.

**My guess:**

The structure of my application can be seen in the repo link above, but in short, the `flask_applicaiton.__init__.py` file contains the `app`. It would appear that the views are not being imported when I run my `gunicorn` command.

That being said, the blueprints are imported and registered as follows:

`flask_applicaiton.__init__.py`

```
# Business Logic
# http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/
# http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/
from flask_application.public.controllers import public
app.register_blueprint(public)

from flask_application.users.controllers import users
app.register_blueprint(users)

from flask_application.admin.controllers import admin
app.register_blueprint(admin)
```

FYI - I will be using nginx to reverse proxy to my application once I have the app running correctly with Gunicorn. At present, nginx shows me:

```
2017/07/11 15:23:35 [error] 1204#1204: *204 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

which I assume is because Gunicorn is not correctly serving the Flask application.

Any suggestions on the cause or how I can debug this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile`

Comment: afraid that doesn't change anything. `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000` also returns a `404`

Comment: Can you show us your flask_application.py?

Comment: there is no `flask_application.py` but flask_application is the directory with an `__init__.py` file inside. [This](https://github.com/hansonkd/FlaskBootstrapSecurity/blob/master/flask_application/__init__.py) is what the file looks like. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem - I'm having something very similar. I'm running a flask-factory style implementation other than that my init is fairly similar. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use gunicorn and flask in virtualenvironment.Instead of:

```
sudo gunicorn flask_application:app -b 127.0.0.1:8000
```

First setup virtualenvironment, activate it. Than `pip install gunicorn`. Also install flask and all other things in venv without `sudo`.

You can check my [repository](https://github.com/ozanonurtek/flask-mvvm-r).